# Regex to extract and parse an array like string in string

Tags: php, regex

I have to create a script parse a path and replace variables with existing array attribute. I have an multi-deminsional array like below:

```
$param = array(
        'titles'=>array(
            '[group1]'=>array(
                array('name'=>'picture','title'=>'personel_image','target_folder'=>'tmp/contacts/{name=picture}[value]'),
                array('name'=>'full_name','title'=>'Full Name'),
                array('name'=>'melli_code','title'=>'id code','format'=>'number'),
                )
        )
)
```

As you can see there is an attribute call target_folder that user write as following format,'tmp/contacts/**{format=number}[title]/{name=picture}[title]**'.

I need a solution to parse a bold part of above path as an array like below.

```
$search_for = array(
        '0'=>array(
            '[array_column]'=>'format',
            '[array_column_keyword']=>'number',
            '[array_column_value']=>'title',
        ),
        '1'=>array(
            '[array_column]'=>'name',
            '[array_column_keyword']=>'picture',
            '[array_column_value']=>'title',
        )
)
```

What is the best way to resolve the above problem?

Comment: It might be possible for fixed format, but is it all it is to the syntax? Do you need to extend the syntax to more complex cases?

Comment: the syntax is fixed. I will replace whole string with variable once the $search_for array is generated.

Comment: What is allowed as format, number, title? `[A-Za-z0-9_]`?

Comment: hmm, yes it's standard characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the format is fixed, and only `[A-Za-z0-9_]` is allowed in the format, you can write the regex as:

```
preg_match('~\{[A-Za-z0-9_]+=[A-Za-z0-9_]+\}\[[A-Za-z0-9_]+\]~', $str, $matches);
```

In non-UTF mode (without `u` flag), you can safely substitute `[A-Za-z0-9_]` with `\w`:

```
preg_match('~\{\w+=\w+\}\[\w+\]~', $str, $matches);
```